# Subtyping proofs

Tags: scala, types, proof

Suppose I have two types `Type1` and `Type2` and (non-diverging) values of type `Type1 <:< Type2` and `Type2 <:< Type1`, is it possible for `Type1` and `Type2` to *not* be the same type?

Assuming such a thing is not possible (and I don't think it is), are the functions in the standard library for manipulating this sort of evidence? For instance, functions like:

```
def eq[A, B](ev1: A <:< B, ev2: B <:< A): A =:= B = ???
def sym[A, B](ev: A =:= B): B =:= A = ???
```

Basically something equivalent to [`Data.Type.Equality`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Type-Equality.html#g:2) in Haskell (but with utilities involving subtyping too).

#### EDIT

I could obviously cheat my way to a couple of primitives, but that sort of defeats the point of using `=:=` and `<:<` in the first place...

```
def eq[A, B](ev1: A <:< B, ev2: B <:< A): A =:= B = =:=.tpEquals[A,A].asInstanceOf
def sym[A, B](ev: A =:= B): B =:= A = =:=.tpEquals[A,A].asInstanceOf
```

Comment: Have a look at how `<:<` is defined in `Predef.scala`, the evidence values are always just the identity function, the evidence doesn't contain any runtime representation of the types involved.